# необходимо записать данные парсера в csv, использую Python 3.8.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
user_database = []
for user in urls:
    r = requests.get(user['href'], headers=HEADERS)
    soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')
    title = soup.find('h1', {'class': 'fn'}).text
    product_code = soup.find('span', {'class': 'code'}).text
    price_usd = soup.find('span', {'class': 'ccy'}).text
    description = soup.find('div', {'class': 'pro_info_parameters'}).text
    link = 'https:' + soup.find('div', {'class': 'wj-content-backtop'}).find('a').get('href')
    image_main = 'https:' + soup.find('img', {'class': 'img400'})['src'].strip()
    #print(title, product_code, price_usd, description, link, image_main)
    user_data = {
        'title': title,
        'product_code': product_code,
        'price_usd': price_usd,
        'description': description,
        'link': link,
        'image_main': image_main
    }
    user_database.append(user_data)
    #print(user_data)
```

Comment: Используйте Pandas, там всё очень просто

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы писать в csv-файл, испортируйте пакет "csv". Пример использования:

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

Взято из документации здесь: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Csv импортирован, все как надо, но записываются только заголовки

Comment: И вы используете writer так же, как в примере? Возможно, вы передаете на writer пустые переменные?